# querystring is too long error in uwp b2c app c#.net app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We are using Microsoft.Identity.Client nuget library version 4.x and we are able to authenticate social identity providers like facebook and also some third-party ones using azure b2c userflows. While authenticating with our Azure AD SSO we get an error in the app which says "Requested query string too long". But on web we have NO such issue.

with some research and support help forums from MS, we identified we need to modify the code from the app side and send a POST Request instead of GET so that SAML request will not error out.

Any idea if Microsoft.Identity.Client nuget library allows us to do that ?

We normally use code like below to initialize the and call acquire token methods.

```
PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AuthServiceConfiguration.ClientId)
            .WithB2CAuthority(AuthServiceConfiguration.Authority)
            .Build();

AuthenticationResult authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(AuthServiceConfiguration.ApiScopes)
                .WithAccount(GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, AuthServiceConfiguration.PolicySignUpSignIn))
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error is thrown for any query string in the URL exceeding this limit. And it’s always a good practice to avoid long query strings in a `ASP.NET` websites.

One way to solve this error is by changing the **maxQueryString** and the **maxUrl** value for the website. And you can do so by adding the following shown in the code snippet to your **`web.config`**.

```xml
...
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
...
```

You may also have to add the following in your **`web.config`**.

```xml
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
```

Note that you don't have use the exact numerical values shown in the above snippets, these numbers are just examples. Read this [Request Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#configuration) document from Microsoft for more information.

You can also set Extra Query Parameters for the query string in the HTTP authentication request using **WithExtraQueryParameters()** method as shown below.

```cs
public T WithExtraQueryParameters (string extraQueryParameters);
```

Here **extraQueryParameters** is the parameter that will be appended as is to the query string in the HTTP authentication request to the authority. For more information check this [WithExtraQueryParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.abstractapplicationbuilder-1.withextraqueryparameters?view=azure-dotnet) document.

Comment: The issue i am facing is in uwp desktop app that uses azure b2c integrated identity with user flows. we dont have our own servers as we are using azure cloud. The authentication is failing with azure b2c having query string too long. Seems like your changes are referring to a webserver? and which method will take extraQueryParameters  ?

Comment: how can i set maxUrlLength length and maxQueryStringLength if i use msal.net lib ?

Comment: will this be a correct way to pass?      

 
authResult = await SingleSignOnManager.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                      .WithExtraQueryParameters("&maxQueryStringLength=32768&maxUrlLength=65536")
                                .ExecuteAsync()
                                .ConfigureAwait(false);